# Will JBPM4 work with Jboss AS 7.2?

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

My current application is running with JBPM 4 on JBoss 4.0.3 application server. We are planning to upgrade Jboss AS to 7.2 in the near future and we want to know the compatibility of JBPM4 with Jboss 7.2. We are unable to find useful documentation on compatibility between JBPM 4 and Jboss AS 7.2. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I wud suggest to migrate jBPM 4 also to latest version (6.X) as i have also worked on 4.x and moved back our application to 3.2.X becuase there was no product support aprat from community(https://developer.jboss.org/thread/150947).

Regarding the documentation and compatibility i think it shud work but again you need to test at your end only.

Post results here so it will be helpfull for other also.